# Can Jekyll act over css or js files?

Tags: javascript, css, liquid, jekyll

I'm using [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) for one of my projects and it really seems a very good alternative for developing simple websites but maintaining some processes automated.

It's nice how the [Liquid Extensions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions) work, so I was wondering if it's possible to make Jekyll act over js and css files too.

So I could have my `main.css` like:

```
@import url("/stylesheets/reset.css?{{site.time | date: '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}}");
@import url("/stylesheets/config.css?{{site.time | date: '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}}");
```

Using some of the helpers I have and also some variables I could create using YML front matter, don't know if it's possible through.

But since it only generated static files I don't see why I wouldn't be able to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yep. You just have to add a YAML block to the file, and Jekyll will process it. The YAML block can be empty:

```
---
---
@import url("/stylesheets/reset.css?{{site.time | date: '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}}");
@import url("/stylesheets/config.css?{{site.time | date: '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try [the Jekyll Assets plugin](https://github.com/jekyll-assets/jekyll-assets), it really helps dealing with CSS and JS assets.