# Jekyll accessing page variables from CSS

Tags: css, image, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to set a `background-img` in my `css.liquid` file, and I need to get YAML variables in the page. How can I do that? This is what I have so far:

```
background-image: url({{ page.locales[page.default_locale][page.first_name] }});
```

I also had this:

```
background-image: url('{{ page.first_name }}{{ page.last_name }}.jpg');
```

Comment: found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4305955/2609042

Answer (score 2):

Just use these styles 'inline' and not in your css.liquid file. That is by far the easiest (and least ugly) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only files with a YAML front matter section, and with the extensions `.html`, `.markdown`, `.md`, or `.textile` get processed by Jekyll.

You could hack this to get it working by saving your CSS file with one of those extensions, and including a YAML front matter section. That seems like a pretty clumsy way to do it, and it'll make for some ugly code, but it might work.

Comment: Could you please add some reference? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `---\n---` at the top of the css file, like so:

```
---
---

.myClass {
   background-image: url('{{ page.first_name }}{{ page.last_name }}.jpg');
}
```

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42528645/2235593